Get original model from a group model
Consider the following scenario. I have a model that is defined like the following code
public class LanguageModel
{
    public CultureInfo? CultureInfo { get; set; }
    public string? LanguageName { get; set; }
    public LanguageModel? Parent { get; set; }
    public string? Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string? Flag { get; set; }
    public bool IsSupported { get; set; } = false;
}

Because I want to group a List to use in a ListView in a MAUI ContentView, I created this one
public class LanguageModelGroup : List<LanguageModel>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public string Flag { get; private set; }

    public LanguageModelGroup(string name, string flag, 
        List<LanguageModel> languages) : base(languages)
    {
        Name = name;
        Flag = flag;
    }
}

Then, I have the extension to group a list
public static List<LanguageModelGroup> 
    ToGroups(this List<LanguageModel> languages)
{
    return languages.GroupBy(x => new { x.Parent.LanguageName, x.Parent.Flag })
                .OrderBy(x => x.Key.LanguageName)
                .Select(x => new LanguageModelGroup(
                    x.Key.LanguageName, 
                    x.Key.Flag, 
                    x.OrderBy(l => l.LanguageName).ToList()))
                .ToList();
}

Based on that, when I click on an item in the ListView, I want to get the original LanguageModel. So, I have this code
private void listLanguages_ItemSelected(object sender, 
    SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    LanguageModel? languageModel = null;
    if(e.SelectedItem is LanguageModel)
        languageModel = (LanguageModel)e.SelectedItem;
}

but obviously, the SelectedItem is a LanguageModelGroup. How can I get the LanguageModel from the LanguageModelGroup?
Update
In the ListView I can define the following DataTemplate
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="md:LanguageModel">

and I get the object I expected.

if you are clicking on an individual item in the list, why is it returning a group?

Because the source of the ListView is a LanguageModelGroup list to display the items group by Name. ListView returns only 1 item of LanguageModelGroup type

you should be able to enumerate LanguageModelGroup to get the set of LanguageModel it contains
